# Are there alternative ways of downloading free applications from Android Market?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, downloading

I can't download applications from the Android Market very well. The most common problem is that it sends an HTTP request and the remote server replies, but no data follows: the TCP connection just stalls. The Market app shows an animated progress bar (before "0%" or sometimes always "0%") indefinitely until I cancel the download.

Sometimes using another network connection helps. (Note: I don't have data plan yet and use only WiFi):

- Connection over Wi-fi access point to my laptop that is running VPN and doing NAT: stalls
- Connection over Wi-fi access point to my laptop that is running VPN and doing "-j REDIRECT' to tcpsocks that is connecting throught "ssh -D" from my server: sometimes works
- Ad-hoc Wi-fi connection to my laptop that is running VPN and doing "-j REDIRECT' to [tcpsocks](https://github.com/vi/tcpsocks) that is connecting throught "ssh -D" from my server: stalls
- Connection over Wi-fi access point to my laptop connected to university network and doing `-j REDIRECT` to tcpsocks that is connecting through the `ssh -D` (connections originating from my server): sometimes works, very very slow
- VPN connection from the device throught the access point (without using laptop): works
- Connecting through the ProxyDroid (running redsocks internally) redirecting to `ssh -D` (connections originating from my server) started on my laptop over Ad-hoc wifi network: stalls
- Connecting through the ProxyDroid (HTTP mode) redirecting to proxy server running on my laptop (with by chain of proxy servers finally originates connections from my server) started on my laptop over Ad-hoc wifi network: stalls

The only workaround I found is to capture the request from device with Wireshark and execute it (using netcat) on my desktop computer. It downloads the apk file from the Market which I can put on the device as usual. Obtaining such links is hovewer inconvenient (especially when it uses HTTPS).

Trying to use ProxyDroid does not help.

- How can I debug stalled downloads from Android Market?
- What are alternative approaches to obtaining apps from Market? Would using the Android Market in the emulator be better?

Comment: Using the emulator would definitely be easier than sniffing the traffic, except for the fact that the emulator doesn't come with the Market.  Did you ever have the Market working before, or is this not a new development?

Comment: It works or not mostly depending on network connection (however sometimes it differs in the same configuration). Sometimes is also downloads, but very very slow.

Comment: BTW looks like my connection problems resolved: http://superuser.com/questions/325379/why-small-tcp-connections-succeeds-but-big-ones-fails/325459

Answer (score 2):

If you can download from your PC without stalling*, you can then copy the `.apk` over to your phone and open/install from the file-system.

---

*Q: how to initate android download in a PC browser?

A: I don't know, but it's possible for other markets, anyway)

Comment: Yes, but it is not easy to obtain direct link to apk file. All markets assume that device itself will download apk file.

I want direct links to apk files that I can download in tricky ways (for example, firstly download to my server, then to my PC and only then copy to device).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using AppBrain http://www.appbrain.com/ it has all the apps from the Android Market but it also lets you push installs from your computer.

Comment: Direct links to apk files: yes or no? I assume "push install" means "tell the device to download apk". If downloading apks from device is _broken_ then it will not work.

Comment: well no, but i figured it was worth trying, i assumed you were looking for things to try. it seems like you should just wipe the phone, your problem seems pretty unusual and not something that you should have to deal with regularly

Comment: It depends mostly not on phone but on network connection. I want it to work with unusual network connections (listed in the question).

Comment: oh im sorry, i misunderstood that to mean that those were things you had tried to fix the situation, not that those were things you wanted to have happen.